# plink command line problem input scrumbled

Tags: powershell, cmd, putty, plink

I'm using plink command line interface because u can provide a password.

As soon ad I'm connected, all input is shredded as follows:

"show pwr" becomes "←7s←7h←7o←7w←7 ←7p←7w←7r←7"
few backspaces and then "test" becomes "←←8←←8←←8←←8←←8←←8←←8←←8←←8←←8←←8←←8←←8←←8←←8←←8←←8←←8←7t←7e←7s←7t←7"

[image: console output]

I have no idea why it does that - if i run it in GIT Bash its working fine. Quick google didn't yield any results. Happening in cmd and powershell.
Please help.

Comment: How are you using Plink? For an interactive use? Or for some automation?

Comment: for automation. its working more or less using it like this `$test = echo "show pwr" | plink admin@192.168.1.5 -pw XXXXXX -no-antispoof`
but id like to know why it behaved like this and how to get rid of it.

Comment: that doesnt get me anywhere. the strange behavior in my case is scrambling the input, not output

Comment: No. Everything you get on the console is **output**. It does not matter that the contents of the *output* is based on your *input*. You can clearly see, that no matter that your command is echoed with ANSI sequences intermingled, the server clearly understood your command.

Comment: yeah, the server understands the command. i dont have any trouble sending commands and reading responses. i would like to know why the input is scrambled like in the printscreen. but anyway ill try the suggestions in the link

Comment: *"i would like to know why the input is scrambled like in the printscreen"* – That is explained in the link I have posted.

Comment: thx, ill try it when i find the time. but you posted the same link twice.